# ErrorHandler for threads different from EDT

Tags: codenameone

For any uncaught exception that occurs in EDT, I show an informative `Dialog` (useful during the development), I send a crash report to the developer account and, when the user press "OK" in the `Dialog`, I kill the app. This logic prevents testers from testing the app in an invalid state, that's why I don't use the default crash report functionality of Codename One, but I reimplemented that according to my needs.

To do that, I used `Display.getInstance().addEdtErrorHandler(...)`, that works fine.

Is there any similar API to automatically handle uncaught exceptions in custom threads, like my `EasyThread` instances? Even better, to automatically handle uncaught exceptions of all threads with few code in the `init()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't have thread groups so there is no uncaught exception handlers. But something like that should probably be available for easy thread. It could be pretty powerful as it could allow for a retry of a failed task.

So we'll add new methods: `addErrorListener`, `removeErrorListener`, `addGlobalErrorListener` and `removeGlobalErrorListener` to the coming update of Codename One.

Comment: Thank you very much Shai, I'll wait for these new APIs :-)